# SQL Query for hourly average through out the month for the same hour

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am stuck in generating a sql query(SQL Server 2008 R2) for a table that has hourly data for a month. Now What I need is, the average of data for 0 t0 1 Am(for complete month), 1Am to 2Am(for complete month), 2Am to 3AM(for complete month) .... 23PM to 23:59PM(for complete month).
my table structure is 
logdatetime||value1||value2 i.e., 11/13/13 0:00||0.2||2.3, 11/13/13 1:00||0.2||2.4 and so on until 11/13/13 23:00||0.2||2.3
My output should be.
0:00 AM||0.2||2.35, 1:00AM||0.2||2.35

the values are average of that particular time for the complete month.

Comment: Average of which field do you want? Value1 or value2?Also, when you say data between 0 AM and 1AM, is it Value1 at 1AM (Minus) Value1 at 0AM. Please elaborate.

Comment: Needed average of Value1 and Value2 in respective columns. No, value1 at 0 Am for all the dates in that month will averaged and , Value1 at 1 AM for all the dates in that month should be average

Comment: similarly for value2 ... This looks like 0AM|| Average of Value1 that falls in this time range for all the dates|| Average of Value2 that falls in this time range for all the dates. Likewise for 1AM,2AM,3AM and so on

Comment: Do you want it for any particular month? like 11th month as your data shows..?

Comment: yes, for a particular month. based on the user input. the example data has 11th month, but it might be different in the real scenario.

Comment: I posted the query below. Let me know if it is what you needed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only need data for particular month and year, here is the query..

`SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),longdate,114),1,2), AVG(VALUE1),AVG(VALUE2)
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE MONTH(LONGDATE) = 11 AND YEAR(LONGDATE) = 2013
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),longdate,114),1,2)`